# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state' in flask

Tags: python, flask

I looked at some other similar questions and it does not seem do be the case but I'm not really sure.

Here is my route:

```
@app.route('/status/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def status(id):
    form = CommentForm()
    
    book = Books.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
    
    if form.validate_on_submit:
        comment = Comments(comment_text=form.comment_text.data, book=book.id)
        db.session.add(comment)
        db.session.commit()
        
        return redirect(url_for("dashboard")) 
    
    bookview = Books.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
    
    return render_template('post.html', bookview=bookview, form=form)
```

Here are my tables:

```
class Books(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author = db.Column(db.String)
    title = db.Column(db.String)
    description = db.Column(db.String)
    comments = db.relationship('Comments', backref='book')
```

```
class Comments(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    comment_text = db.Column(db.String)
    perent = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('books.id'))
```

Here is my html

```
<form method="POST">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.comment_text) }}
    

    <button type="submit">Comment</button>

</form>
```

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong, I feel like it should be working.

Here is the entire error:

[Here is the entire error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auRK2.png)

Comment: Can you add the entire error stack trace? It might have additional information like the line number where the error is getting raised.

Comment: @RedowanDelowar I added a screenshot of the error, i'm assuming its what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of referencing `book=book.id`, when you create a new comment, just reference the actual object:

```
comment = Comments(comment_text=form.comment_text.data, book=book)
```

When you create the `book` backref SQLAlchemy expects it to be an SQLAlchemy object instance. Since you're assigning an `int` to `book`, the ORM tries to deal with with like an SQLAlchemy object, hence the `'int' object has no attribute _sa_instance_state` (thats SQLAlchemy trying to access this attribute).

If you want to assign the `int` value instead of the object, assign it to the `perent` column:

```
comment = Comments(comment_text=form.comment_text.data, perent=book.id)
```

Also, I suggest you to remove the Flask-Login `UserMixin` from them `Comments` model. It's probably a `ctrl+c/ctrl+v` mistake.